# Greatest common divisor of multiples

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the GCD of $3 \times 5^2 \times 7^2 \times 11^2$ and $3^2 \times 5^4 \times 11^3$?

I can use the euclidean algorithm but is there an easier way to simplify this to make it more simple?  If someone could help me out on editing that would help as well.

Comment: Look at the primes. You could even explicitly list the divisors of each number pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have each of the numbers written as a product of their prime factors, it's now a simple process of picking the lowest exponent of each prime factor.

For instance, the GCD of $5^2$, $5^5$ and $5 ^9$ will be $5 ^2$ (since $5^2$ is clearly a factor of the two other higher powers of 5)

Using the same logic, the GCD of $3^1 \times 5^2 \times 7^2 \times 11^2$ and $3^2 \times 5^4 \times 7^0 \times 11^3$ is simply **$3^1 \times 5^2 \times 7^0 \times 11^2$** which equals **9075**